# How to COPY files of current directory to folder in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that copies all the files in the currently directory to a specific folder.

Currently I have

```
COPY . /this/folder
```

I'm unable to check the results of this command, as my container closes nearly immediately after I run it. Is there a better way to test if the command is working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can start a container and check.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm <DOCKER_IMAGE> sh
$ ls -l /this/folder
```

If your docker image has `ENTRYPOINT` setting, then run below command:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --entrypoint sh <DOCKER_IMAGE>
$ ls -l /this/folder
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is only for testing, include the below command in your docker file:

```
RUN cd /this/folder && ls
```

This will list the directory contents while docker build

Comment: I got error "The command '/bin/sh -c ls' returned a non-zero code: 1 when adding just RUN ls to Dockerfile